# Nginx TCP forwarding based on first date package

Tags: nginx, tcp, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Nginx TCP forwarding based on some filed of tcp header is ok. I would like to route the tcp connection via the first package data.
For example, first receive message = A1 -> server1, first receive message = A2 -> server2.

I have taken a look at the TCP guides and the module documentation, but it doesn't seem well referenced. If anyone can point me to the right direction, i'd be grateful.